как распаковать zip архив с коммандной строки в windows 10 в указанную папку без установки каких либо программ
как распаковать zip архив с коммандной строки в windows 10 в указанную папку без установки каких либо программ

Cредства распаковки архивов (входящие в состав ZIP, RAR, 7Z) не требуют установки и бесплатны.

В windows 10 есть PowerShell 5 в комплекте. Можно с его помощью: Expand-Archive C:\Test\test.zip  -DestinationPath c:\unzip

@AndrewHobbit оформите в виде ответа :)

@ViktorTomilov оформил :)

В windows 10 есть PowerShell 5 в комплекте. Можно с его помощью:
Expand-Archive C:\Test\test.zip -DestinationPath c:\unzip

